# AngularJs setting input as ng-invalid ng-invalid-required while using a ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I have a form with a buch of inputs with only one validation (`required`). I have a css rule for `.form-control.ng-dirty.ng-invalid-required` to set the text red. When the page loads everything is good because they have the `ng-pristine` class and all the `ng-model` for those inputs are being set to the correspondent input value, but now and then (not 100% of the times) those inputs get the `ng-invalid ng-invalid-required` classes from the start. When I start to type the input becomes red because it gets the class `ng-dirty` attached to the `ng-invalid`. I can't understand why AngularJS puts my input as invalid while the whole form gets `$valid` `true`. The only way that input becomes valid is to delete the whole string and begin to type it again.

My input looks like this when I start to type:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-model="textEn" required="" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```

And on the template it looks like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="textEn" required ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: then what you want? how your validation should work?

Comment: Does this ever happen on complete page-reload ctrl+f5?

Comment: can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle/plunkr?